# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 3 Error in creation of triple array

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I have two lists and a integer:

```
LinkedList<Integer> Origin = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                Origin.add(0,1);
                Origin.add(1,2);
                Origin.add(2,3);

                LinkedList<Integer> Dest = new LinkedList<Integer>();
                Dest.add(0,2);
                Dest.add(1,3);
                Dest.add(2,1);

                int K=2;
```

Than i create this double with these values:

```
double[][] c=[[0.5, 0.4, 0], [0, Infinity, Infinity], [0.4, 0, Infinity]]
```

Now i would create a new matrix with these values, but using as index the values of the lists. So for the first cell [Origin=1, Dest=2]i should obtain 0.5.

Plus, after this, i would add a new index for the integer K. For every k i would see the double repeated. So, for k=0 i have all the values, for k=1 the same.

This is my code but it's not working.

```
 double[][][]CC=new double[N][N][K];
                 for (int k=1;k<K;k++) {
                    CC[k]=new double[N][N];
                 for (int i = 0; i <Origin.size(); i++){
                       for (int j = 0; j <Dest.size(); j++){
                           CC[Origin.get(i)][Dest.get(j)][k]=c[i][j];      
                       System.out.println( Arrays.deepToString(CC));
                       }
                 }
                 }
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The values in both `Origin` and `Dest` are 1, 2 and 3.  The indexes in the first two dimensions of `CC` are 0, 1 and 2.  So you get that problem as soon as your program finds a 3 in `Origin` or in `Dest`.

Comment: ok, thanks! But if i want to create a new double with the same values, but with a new index the code is ok? I mean, for example i want to copy the values for every k

Comment: Natalia, it's really impossible to see what you're trying to do.  Why don't you post the whole class, along with an explanation of what you're trying to achieve?  That would be better than a few snippets with a description of each one.

Comment: yes, i'm sorry. Is it more clear now?

Comment: OK, I think that as well as the problem I mentioned earlier, you've got your indexes in the wrong order.  I think you need `CC` to be `new double[K][N][N]`.  But you still need to store `0, 1, 2` in `Origin` and `Dest`, not `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: ok thanks, but 1,2,3 are the values and 0,1,2 the position of the list. Is it wrong in the way i have written?

Comment: Yes, because on the line `CC[Origin.get(i)][Dest.get(j)][k]=c[i][j];`, you're using those values as indexes.  And array indexes always start from zero.

Comment: @NataliaSacco, if you need a value's index in the list you should use Origin.indexOf(i), as Dawood said not the get(i).  And you get -1 if it does not exist.